# loading jquery dynamically - $(document).ready() gives '$ is not defined'

Tags: jquery

I have a situation that by checking a flag, I need to dynamically load 1 or more .js files to the page. I want all of these files to load and be ready before the page code starts executing. It appears that the .js files are loading correctly, however an error occurs on the $(document).ready(function(){}); on the page. Here is my "skinny" version of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (typeof ScriptLoaded == 'undefined') {
   var scripts = ["js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"];
   for (i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
      script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = scripts[i];
      script.onload = oCallback();
      script.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') {
            oCallback();
         }
      }
      head.appendChild(script)
   }
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
   alert("ready");
 });

 function oCallback() {
 }
</script>
```

I am loading more than 1 .js file in this routine, but only have jQuery specified here for simplicity. Whenever this code executes, I get the error '$ is not defined'. My callback routine does nothing - just wanting to ignore callback so that file is fully loaded.

I know I have something wrong here - I'm just not understanding it.

Thank you!

---

**Update**

Seems that the oCallback() function is called prior to the script being completely loaded, or the code is fully inserted into the DOM. After some trial and error, it seems this works in both IE and FF:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (typeof ScriptLoaded == 'undefined') {
   var scripts = ["js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"];
   for (i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
      script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = scripts[i];
      script.onload = oCallback();
      script.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') {
            oCallback();
         }
      }
      head.appendChild(script)
   }
 }

 function oCallback() {
 }

 function oReady() {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("ready");
     });
 }
 window.onload = oReady;
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try node? http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 2):

You must this code

`$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("ready");
 });`

write in callback after loaded script.

Or try write one global callback run after loaded all external js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 if (typeof ScriptLoaded == 'undefined') {
   var scripts = ["js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"];
   for (i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
      var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
      script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = scripts[i];
      script.onload = oCallback();
      script.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 'loaded' || this.readyState == 'complete') {
            oCallback();

            if(i === scripts.length - 1)
                  globalCallback();
         }
      }
      head.appendChild(script)
   }
 }

 function oCallback() {
 }

 function globalCallback() {
     $(document).ready(function() {
        alert("ready");
     });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you dbucki, but that only works for IE. I will try to put the $(document).ready(function(){}) in the oCallBack() routine.

Comment: Probably oCallback() is run later then DOM ready event. Try use only `alert("ready");`  without `$(document).ready();`

Comment: That works. Seems like oCallback() is run before the DOM ready event if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

When you attempt to dynamically load the script it must be fetched via http. This request is placed into the javascript task queue. The current task continues to execute code when found. The next line of code found is a call to `$` (remember that jQuery is still loading in the task queue at this point). As a result `$` is undefined. A short time later jQuery finishes loading and the task in the queue executes its code which makes a call to your callback function.

In order to use `$` you must wait for the task to complete execution, and to do this you should place that code in your callback.

```
function oCallback() {
 $(document).ready(function() {
  alert("ready");
 });
}
```

Comment: That still does not work. I continue to get the '$ is not defined' error message.

Comment: BTW, this fails exactly the same way on IE10 and FF28.